# Circumvent the limitation of C# and pass collection of child elements

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App I used c# 5.0. And I need to call the method which takes collection of base class, by passing collection of child class:

```
    public class Foo // base class
    {
         public int fooVariable = 1;
         public void fooMethod(){....};  
    }
    public class Bar:Foo // child class

    public void DoSomething(Foo foo)
    public void DoSomething(List<Foo> foos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(foo.i);  //access to variable
            foo.fooMethod();         //access to method
            foo.i = 10;              //!!!i can change variable!!!
        }
    }

    private List<Bar> _list;
    public void Call()
    {
        DoSomething(new Bar());         // ok
        _list = new List<Bar>();
        list.Add(new Bar());            // I can add a lot of items.
        DoSomething(list);              // not ok

        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(foo.i);  // in console I need to see '10'
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to circumvent such limitation? If yes - how?

**UPD**

In `DoSomething` I neeed full access to all public methods/variables(read/write) /properties(read/write)

Comment: You can always create a `List<Foo>` and put `Bar`s into it.

Comment: And if I need to call any method or get any property from the item of this list - i need evety time cast item to 'Foo'. Also I think 'binding' may break.

Comment: What does `DoSomething` need to *do* with the list? Could you change the signature to `IEnumerable<Foo>` instead? Without more information, this question can't really be answered.

Comment: I edit my question and yes, I can change signature to 'IEnumerable<Foo>'. Generally - I need access to public methods/properties/variables declarated on 'Foo'

Comment: assuming you can have a variable for your list you could call DoSomething like DoSomething(new List<Foo>(variable)); Or also depending on what you are doing in DoSomething you could possibly use ConvertAll on your list<Bar>

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your attention.  I edited again my question and I think it fully describes my situation now.

Comment: @JarrettRobertson, thanks for your attention. I edited again my question and I think it fully describes my situation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DoSomething(List<Foo> foos)` only actually needs to iterate over the list. So you can change it to:

```
public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
{
    // Body as before
}
```

Now you can pass in a `List<Bar>` to that method due to the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `T`.